# MySQL JOIN / IN performance optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    p.date_created,
    p.description, 
    p.last_edited, 
    p.link, 
    p.link_description, 
    p.link_image_url, 
    p.link_title, 
    p.total_comments, 
    p.total_votes, 
    p.type_id, 
    p.user_id 
FROM posts p JOIN posts_to_tribes ptt ON p.post_id=ptt.post_id 
WHERE ptt.tribe_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
GROUP BY p.post_id 
ORDER BY p.last_edited DESC, p.total_votes DESC LIMIT 25
```

In a non-concurrent environment this query runs ~172ms but in concurrent environment runs 1-2 sec(during the performance testing).

**EXPLAIN output:**

[image]

*Indexes on posts_to_tribes table:*

[image]

Is any way in order to improve performance here ?

Comment: there might be an index on ptt.tribe_id

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any field used in a "decision" context (join, where, order by) should have an index on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have added an index on posts_to_tribes.tribe_id but nothing changed.. the query runs ~188ms right now.. may be I'm doing something wrong..

Comment: Why is a 172ms execution time acceptable, but a 1-2 second execution time is unacceptable?

Comment: I have REST endpoint over this functionality.. right now it runs ~6sec in a concurrent environment during performance testing while other endpoints run ~2-3 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a composite index for `posts_to_tribes`:  `INDEX(tribe_id, post_id)`.

The `GROUP BY` was to compensate for the `JOIN` exploding the number of rows.  Here is a better workaround, than `IN ( SELECT ... )`:

```
SELECT  p.post_id, p.date_created, p.description, p.last_edited,
        p.link, p.link_description, p.link_image_url, p.link_title,
        p.total_comments, p.total_votes, p.type_id, p.user_id
    FROM  posts p
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  DISTINCT  post_id
            FROM  posts_to_tribes
            WHERE  tribe_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      ) AS ptt USING (post_id)
    ORDER BY  p.last_edited DESC,
              p.total_votes DESC
    LIMIT  25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This query runs ~140ms

Comment: One more question, do we need indexes on p.last_edited and p.total_votes ?

Comment: No.  I don't believe that `INDEX(last_edited, total_votes)` (composite, in that order) would do any good.  (1) It will start with the subquery, which does not let it get to that index. (2) Those sound like columns that will be changed a lot, hence overhead in `UPDATE`.  You will be stuck with a "filesort".

Comment: What am I missing? This query will return duplicate rows...?

Comment: Oops -- adding `DISTINCT` to my subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You have applied a `JOIN` operation, when you really wanted to apply a [semi-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29) between your two tables (semi-join in SQL is implemented using `IN` or `EXISTS` predicates).

Because you used the wrong type of `JOIN`, you have then removed the duplicate records again using `GROUP BY`. That's a lot of wasted CPU cycles right there.

The following query will be much faster:

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    p.date_created,
    p.description, 
    p.last_edited, 
    p.link, 
    p.link_description, 
    p.link_image_url, 
    p.link_title, 
    p.total_comments, 
    p.total_votes, 
    p.type_id, 
    p.user_id 
FROM posts p 
WHERE p.post_id IN (
  SELECT ptt.post_id
  FROM posts_to_tribes ptt
  WHERE ptt.tribe_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)
ORDER BY p.last_edited DESC, p.total_votes DESC LIMIT 25
```

You should still have indexes on `(p.post_id)` and `(ptt.tribe_id, ptt.post_id)`

Comment: Thanks, now this query runs ~156ms Also, I'll check it in my performance testing in a concurrent environment

Comment: Did you put an index on both columns of `ptt` as I've indicated?

Comment: In posts_to_tribes I have a PK on (tribe_id, post_id). Also in posts table post_id is also PK. Should I add a separate index on these fields ?

Comment: @alexanoid: Aha, OK. No the PK should be sufficient. I'm sorry, my MySQL knowledge is too limited. I'm sure this would've optimised your query in Oracle, though...