# Mysql denormalizing a join table with many_2_many

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have 3 tables - posts, posts_groups and groups with MANY_2_MANY relationships between posts and groups. In order to get all posts from a specific groups I need to join posts and posts_groups tables. The join is really slow right now. I have described the pretty similar case here [MySQL JOIN / IN performance optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872163/mysql-join-in-performance-optimization)

I think, in order to improve performance I need to denormalize this structure. What is the best practices in MySQL for this ? Can I create a new table for posts where I'll have some kind of hash for groups where this posts participated in ? Based on this hash I'll be able to query all posts from a specific groups by single select. If no, could you please suggest the most appropriate way in order to improve performance for this structure ?

**UPDATED**

The sample query:

```
SELECT  p.post_id, p.date_created, p.description, p.last_edited,
        p.link, p.link_description, p.link_image_url, p.link_title,
        p.total_comments, p.total_votes, p.type_id, p.user_id
    FROM  posts p
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  DISTINCT  post_id
            FROM  posts_to_groups
            WHERE  group_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      ) AS ptt USING (post_id)
    ORDER BY  p.last_edited DESC,
              p.total_votes DESC
    LIMIT  25
```

This query works fast only in non-concurrent environment - **~150ms**. Under performance testing(JMeter) with ~50 concurrent users it shows **5sec**.

**CREATE TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `description` text,
    `link` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `total_votes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `total_comments` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `link_title` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
    `link_description` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
    `link_image_url` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
    KEY `fk_post_type_id` (`type_id`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_post_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `post_types` (`post_type_id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=109919 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `posts_to_groups` (
    `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`,`post_id`),
    KEY `post_to_groups_fk_post_id` (`post_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `post_to_groups_fk_post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`post_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `post_to_groups_fk_group_id` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`group_id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `groups` (
    `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `description` text NOT NULL,
    `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `total_members` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `total_posts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
    KEY `user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`description`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1288 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: We have a lot of relationships (Many_2_Many) and it works fast, do you have indexes on those table ? And you can add your query, we will look for it

Comment: Make sure that your query is making use of **appropriate indexes**. Likely, your query could benefit from covering indexes, or multi-column indexes. (The "add an index on each separate column" is rarely the most appropriate approach.)

Comment: I have updated my question. Also, I have all indexes there, details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872163/mysql-join-in-performance-optimization

Comment: Well you are not doing a simple three table join here, so there are a few other things that could be problematic (like why do subselect?)  You should post your table schema here to get better advice.

Comment: In the other question you said it became slower after adding `DISTINCT` to the subquery. Can you add it to the main query instead?

Comment: GolezTrol, It slows down the query in ~2 times

Comment: How many rows are in the posts table? Do you have an index on post_id in the posts table?

Comment: posts ~110000 rows, post_id is PK, posts_to_groups ~320000 rows, composite PK(post_id, group_id)

Comment: Given that you only want the 25 most recently edited posts, have you tried adding a repeating index on `last_edited` to the `posts` table, and adding a `where` clause to restrict `last_edited` to the last 24 hours (assuming this will always return enough records)?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the three tables.

Comment: I have added CREATE TABLE for these tables

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're doing a semi-join.  The usual method for that is with an EXISTS expression:

```
SELECT  p.post_id, p.date_created, p.description, p.last_edited,
        p.link, p.link_description, p.link_image_url, p.link_title,
        p.total_comments, p.total_votes, p.type_id, p.user_id
FROM  posts p
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM posts_to_groups
        WHERE post_id = p.post_id
            AND group_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    )
ORDER BY  p.last_edited DESC,
          p.total_votes DESC
LIMIT  25;
```

Or, since there's just one key field, you can try an IN expression:

```
SELECT  p.post_id, p.date_created, p.description, p.last_edited,
        p.link, p.link_description, p.link_image_url, p.link_title,
        p.total_comments, p.total_votes, p.type_id, p.user_id
FROM  posts p
WHERE post_id IN (
        SELECT post_id
        FROM posts_to_groups
        WHERE group_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    )
ORDER BY  p.last_edited DESC,
          p.total_votes DESC
LIMIT  25;
```

The IN expression might work better depending on your data and the version of MySQL you're running.  Older versions had problems optimizing EXISTS.

In both cases, I would expect there to be an index on `(posts.post_id)` as well as an index on `(posts_to_groups.post_id, posts_to_groups.group_id)`.

---

Second attempt:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p.post_id, p.date_created, p.description, p.last_edited,
        p.link, p.link_description, p.link_image_url, p.link_title,
        p.total_comments, p.total_votes, p.type_id, p.user_id
FROM  posts p
JOIN  posts_to_groups pg
      ON p.post_id = pg.post_od
WHERE pg.group_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ORDER BY  p.last_edited DESC,
          p.total_votes DESC
LIMIT  25;
```

Comment: MySQL tends to be less performant with Exists/In than with JOIN, unlike most other RDBMSs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, EXISTS version ~422ms, IN - 0.170ms. Right now I'm using the same query(with DISTINCT on inner SELECT) and the results in a concurrent environment are pretty slow. This is why I'm thinking on denormalization in a some way..

Comment: @alexanoid Ok, what about moving the DISTINCT to the outer query?  It should evaluate as SELECT DISTINCT, then ORDER BY, then LIMIT, so it should be logically identical.  See my update above.  Otherwise, my guess is you'll have to mess about with temp tables, which seems pretty gross with 50 concurrent users.

Comment: moving the DISTINCT to the outer query slows down the things in~ 2 times